# Backfeeding Cord

Tags: electrical, generator

I know, I know I shouldn't do it, but I just built a cord to backfeed my house with my generator (120v 20A, 3550w).

One side plug is a 3 pin lock plug that goes into the generator and the other side is a plug that goes into my garage heater outlet (240v, 30A). The cord is a 12/3 gauge with 3 wires that O plug as per notice.

So I decided to try it today, disconnecting the main circuit breaker and all sub system circuit breakers. I started the generator and plugged it in. I then turned on the garage heater circuit breaker and the fridge and lights circuit breakers.

Didn't work... Any ideas why?

By the way, the garage heater circuit goes straight to the main panel through a thermostat (which was turned on to max).

Comment: Can you post a picture of the inside of your panel, along with labeling the breakers you called out in your post? There's a lot wrong with this, but the picture and labels are necessary to answer your question

Comment: My panel is all labelled in french which i understand.Do you think it could be that its maybe when i built the cord, i should have tied the hot on both pins (on the 240V plug) and neutral and groud together on the groud pin.

Comment: Post the photo and add translations (either by scribbling them on the photo, or separately as part of the post).  There's lots of stuff wrong with what you did, most likely, but we can get you on a path to being able to plug your generator in *safely* next time it's called for if we know what's going on here.

Comment: Also, does your generator have a 4 prong receptacle of any sort on it?

Comment: No it only has 3 pins receptacles, 1 at 20A, 1 at 30A (for camping stuff)

Comment: Wait, are you in Europe???

Comment: No in French Canada

Comment: Looks like my pictures are too heavy to upload. The plug i use to backfeed (Garage heater) is a 3 pins, i tied 1 pin to hot, 1 pin to white, 1 pin to neutral with that setting do i get both phase of my all system fed or do i need to tie the green and white together on ground and jump the 2 others pins on the hot ?

Comment: I think I see part of the problem. Generator 120 trying to backfeed via 240 heater receptacle. At a minimum that gets confusing. Can you post the model # of the generator?

Comment: You would never tie the green and white together.

Comment: My generaor is a Champion 3550W

Comment: To a fair extent, it actually doesn't matter what language your panel labels are in. We can at least determine if you are powering the correct half of the circuits in it. Thankfully Canadian electricity and US electricity are the same (unlike the Europeans...)

Comment: Wait, you're backfeeding *through a thermostat*?  Seriously though, are you trolling us here?

Comment: First of all, your ENTIRE HOUSE can run on just 20 amps? Not likely. Those things are called "SUICIDE PLUGS" for a reason. PLEASE DON'T USE THIS CONFIGURATION!!! Even if you are mindful enough to pull the main breaker before using it, when your refrigerator and furnace or air conditioner turned on at the same time it will cost you! Read the thread for better ways of doing this. And if you DON'T remember to pull the main breaker you can injure a power company employee!!!

Answer (score 6):

You know your approach is wrongheaded and dangerous.  **But that's also because it is not necessary**.

We'll do my favorite trick: *Permanent* wiring methods *temporarily*.  In other words, wire it up all Code legal like it'll be there for 50 years, and then 50 hours later, undo it.

It is perfectly legal to install an *inlet* on your home that powers any number of *outlets* in your home.  It's also legal to use flexible cord for the inlet, if it's to be frequently unplugged.

Going into your heater socket is bad because there's a thermostat in the way. So instead, we'll go into the thermostat location.   But hold that thought.

### Rewiring the service panel

First, in the panel, we take some photos (this can be done well in advance), and  identify the circuits we want on generator backup.  We also identify the fat 10 AWG cable going to the heater.  It'll have a black and white wire.   We take the **black** wire, and join it to all the black wires from each of the circuits we need to power on generator.

Now here's the tricky part: we follow each circuit black wire, back to its cable, and identify the **white** wires also in that bundle. We pull those off the neutral bar, and join them to the white from the heater.  Don't just leave them all on the neutral bar; pull them off. This is important, because the generator GFCI will trip if you don't.

If any of these cables have a red wire also, you need to figure out whether you need red or black, and connect that one to the black bundle.  If the wire is 12 AWG, you can just connect both to the black bundle.

At this point, none of the wires for the heater circuit or desired circuits are on breakers or neutral bar anymore.  They are nutted to each other, using the service panel as nothing but a splice box.  This is Code legal.

The ground wires, leave them where they are.

### At the thermostat

Now, back at the thermostat.  Open up the thermostat, take photos of the existing wiring as-it-is.  If you feel it'll help later, mark some wires with tape before taking the photos.  Now, remove the thermostat, and store it.

Now, we need a heavy duty 12 AWG appliance extension cord.  Oh hey, that suicide cord you already faked up needs to be destroyed *anyway*... so let's kill two birds with one stone.  The 240V (NEMA 6-30) plug you added -- remove it.  Get to black, white and bare.

Now, get an appropriate blank cover plate for the thermostat box.  Except we need a cover plate with a knockout on it.  We also need a proper strain relief for that cord; an electrical supply house will have no trouble setting you up if you bring in the cord. Install the cord in the blank cover plate, with the strain relief, and secure it.

Now, in the thermostat box, identify the cable that goes back to the service panel (not the one going to the heater).  With those wires, splice cord bare to cable bare, cord white to cable white, and cord black to cable black.

Install the cover plate and screw it down.  Now you have a flexible cord coming out where the thermostat had been, with a plug on the end.  This is a code-legal *inlet*.

The use of a flexible cord is legal because this will be connected and disconnected frequently.  As in, twice.

Once the crisis is over, rollback the wiring to the way you found it.  Take the cable-with-cover-plate-on-the-end, and throw it in the emergency kit for next time.

### The one Code problem here

Presuming the generator's circuit breaker trips at 20A, we may be connecting 14 AWG /15A circuits to a 20A breaker, which would violate NEC 240.4's statutory limit of 15A on #14.  (thermally it's allowed 20A at 75C temp).  However, the practical likelihood of overloading them is low, since you'll be powering several circuits off one 20A breaker, and it's unlikely for one 15A circuit to gobble up more than 75% of total available power.

Comment: This is excellent advice. Instead of berating the OP,  you gave them a better way to safely do it.

Answer (score 3):

> Asked 4 years,  8 months ago  Modified today

- bro, you still around?
- as soon as he mentioned in the comment *My generator is a Champion 3550W*

  - https://www.championpowerequipment.com/product/200911-3550-watt-generator/
  - That < 5000 watt size not to mention simply looking it up it don't have 240v outlets.  So connecting it into his 240v garage heater outlet, he put a generator neutral to a hot leg of his house panel so only one 120v side of his house load panel breakers will have worked, at best.
  - And he had no neutral going back to the generator from the house panel (because it was connected to a hot leg in the panel) which is why he had no power at all in the house.
- And then if I interpret correctly what he said - the connection is going through his [electric] garage heater outlet which is on a thermostat, I assume a 240v ~2000 watt type of thermostat he did not clarify and is likely why he stated he turned the garage heat thermostat max.. was in order to close that circuit between the generator and house load center panel.  But then, whatever that thermostat is rated at for to turning on & off the electric heater, lets say 2000 watts for example, you have the possibility of a 3500w (4500w peak) generator putting greater power through a device {that thermostat} that's only rated for 2000 watts or whatever it may be.

  - Not necessarily a big deal if all you want to do is conveniently turn on some lights or operate one small appliance and have good judgement, but not recognizing the 120v only generator connecting to the 240v heater outlet... doesn't give me confidence he would have recognized that detail.  Between your suicide plug and the assisted thing (MAID) you folks don't have it easy up there.
  - I think the 6' electric baseboard heater I had in my finished basement was something like 240v @ 1500 watts, they vary, the wall thermostat is simply in series on one of the 240v legs to the heater.  From what he described (and hasn't described) it sounds like it's that type of thermostat going to a 240v outlet that the garage heater (not having an internal thermostat) is plugged in to rather than being hardwired to the panel breaker.
- the fact this went 4 years with the only answers being *OMG that's against code* should give one pause when thinking they've gotten an answer here in this forum.  Zero excuse for having 10k + points to your username and not immediately recognizing he had a 120v only generator and what he did.
- hoping the original poster responds, interested to know how things worked out for you since this was asked in 2018.  I suspect this was the least of his problems since then.

Comment: You have some good points here, but they're _very_ difficult to find in this wall of text. Please [edit] your answer to provide some formatting to make it easier to read.

Comment: A 240 volt heater should have a the thermostat in series with both legs so when off there's no voltage on either hot wire "downstream" of the thermostat.  I've seen a 240 volt thermostat put in series on one leg of two circuits so one thermostat ran two baseboard heaters.  That made me very nervous about what other electrical surprises I might find in that house.  I don't like 120 volt surprises.